# Pandas - Different time formats in the same column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe that has dates stored in different formats in the same column as shown below:

```
date
1-10-2018
2-10-2018
3-Oct-2018
4-10-2018
```

Is there anyway I could make all of them to have the same format.

Comment: There are only these 2 formats?

Comment: @jezrael, yes just these two types are there in this column

Comment: And what is excepted output?

Comment: Just want to make the format uniform, it can either be 1-10-2018 or 1-Oct-2018

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with specify [formats](http://strftime.org/) with `errors='coerce'` for replace not matched values to `NaN`s. Last [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) for replace missing values by `date2` Series.

```
date1 = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d-%m-%Y', errors='coerce')
date2 = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d-%b-%Y', errors='coerce')

df['date'] = date1.combine_first(date2)
print (df)
        date
0 2018-10-01
1 2018-10-02
2 2018-10-03
3 2018-10-04
```